# At least, how many threads are needed to run an async task?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

This was an interview question asked by a senior manager.

At least, how many threads are needed to run an async task?

I said that at least one thread is needed, but I'm not sure if I said it right or not.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html Often none at all. It depends if the task is awaiting something or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model#BKMK_Threads):

> Async methods don't require multithreading because an async method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the method is active.

You gave the correct answer.

Comment: That might technically be true but "when the method is active" it uses a thread.  The fact that it might not be very active most of the time doesn't mean it doesn't ever use a thread, 'something' has to do the work.

Comment: Exactly. So, at least 1 thread is indeed needed to "run an async task".

Comment: @Neil Depends if there is any work to be done. For example `Task.Delay(-1)` doesn't require any threads at all to run.

Comment: @Charlieface NOP does nothing, news at 11 ! :-)